# how logback watches configure file

Tags: java, log4j, logback

I heard Logback is not using separate thread to watch configure file like log4j to avoid shutdown issue. But I couldn't find any material talking about how they impl it. There are some discussion in logback mail list back to 2007. Anyone can point to some material talking about the mechanism, pros & cons? Thanks

Comment: Did a bit of digging but didn't find everything. [Here's a good place to start, though.](https://github.com/ceki/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/ConfigurationWatchList.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a `TurboFilter` that wraps all logging calls. Every 16 logging calls a timer will be checked if it has elapsed and, if it has, the config file(s) will be checked for modification.

So they avoid a separate thread by stealing a tiny bit of time in calls to log methods.

Comment: As I understand, log4j's file watchdog thread might cause issue in an application env. So I think it's still safe in a pojo program, right?

Comment: It's all about stopping that thread. If it's a daemon thread, it's safe in a plain Java app.

Comment: Thanks, @marko-topolnik. I have a follow-up question regarding logback. Appreciate your response. I have 2 env env1: log caller directly invoke logback. env2: a queue decouple log caller and logging thread. The log statement could be case 1. log.debug("this is %s", s); case 2. log.debug(s); I don't understand without log guard how argument string "s" can not be evaluated before invoking logback method stack in any case above. Is this due to sharing heap in a single JVM?

Comment: All arguments are always evaluated. The only benefit of that placeholder syntax is that the final string won't have to be produced, and that implies that `toString` won't have to be called on all the arguments. In many practical circumstances this really is a great benefit.

Comment: Thanks, @marko-topolnik. I don't really understand param evaluation after reading java spec. Here is my understanding for general java param evaluation: 1) all param will be evaluated to the type of method and "The argument expressions (possibly rewritten as described above) are now evaluated to yield argument values" in spec. So no s1+s2+s3 in logback parameterized argu method which seems defeat the benefit of lazy evaluation. 2) is it because evaluation process only calc ref instead of value and pass by ref to the method?

Comment: 3) with queue decoupling log caller and logging thread, with a queue appender impl, do I have to use log guard in order not to serialize unnecessary msg? Thx.